# Как получить информацию о процессоре?

Tags: ассемблер

есть такая функция которая даёт информацию о процессоре. Конкретно изготовитель.

;FASM

;BIOS

*Я только начал изучать FASM*

**По возможности поставьте комментарии на против каждой строчки**

```
get_processor_manufacturer:
    mov eax, 0
    cpuid    ;EAX=0001h
    mov dword ptr manufacturer, ebx
    mov dword ptr manufacturer+4, edx
    mov dword ptr manufacturer+8, ecx
    ret
```

Как получить остальную информацию?

Comment: А "остальную" это какую ? Вот например для начала статью посмотрите https://habr.com/ru/company/intel/blog/220851/ (обратите внимание на список литературы внизу, там есть например ссылки на официальную доку интела, где как обещают более 40 страниц поcвещано различным аспектам CPUID)

Comment: Ну например количество ядер, я знаю что есть документация но она не для новичка а если начать это всё изучать тогда вопросы отпадут сами собой и зачем тогда нужен сайт https://ru.stackoverflow.com/?)

Comment: Функцию я сам написал по примерам лазил по форумам но я не знаю куда двигаться дальше есть допустим информация как получить модель процессора но там до того сложно

Comment: Но вы сейчас задаете общий вопрос "как найти любую информацию о процессоре". А ответ на нее должен занимать страниц 100. это не формат stackoverflow

Comment: Хорошо как узнать модель процессора?

Comment: Mike ссылку которую вы указали я там ещё не был) И по моему это то что нужно) Побежал изучать, спасибо!

Comment: Конкретно количество _логических_ ядер cpuid с eax=1 возвращается в битах 16-23 регистра EBX.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/106820/discussion-between--and-mike).